# Trying to make a Digital SAT format

Tags: tables, environments

I'm in a bit of a bind, hoping to get some help.  My knowledge of LaTeX is rudimentary at best, and I was asked to make a template that follows the structure of the Digital SAT questions.

Hoping someone could point me in a direction to complete something like this.  What packages to utilize, what documents to use, etc.  All the help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Well what is Digital SAT questions?

Comment: @Mensch slack isn't letting me attach a photo, but you can google any dsat question and that's the format I want to go for.  Sorry for no specifics, I'm trying to figure this out myself.

Comment: Welcome. // If you have little experience with Latex, why do you think it‘s a good approach, e.g. compared to your favorite word processor?

Comment: @MS-SPO not my choice. i was informed it had to be done in latex and was asked to do so.

Comment: That's an unreasonable demand of a student/employee/contractor/etc. with little or no experience using LaTeX. Whoever is demanding this either needs to find somebody with the relevant background or train somebody so they have that background. If they aren't prepared to do that, say no. If you aren't able to say no, prepare the thing in your favourite word processor and throw it through a conversion tool. The result will not be pretty, but it should approximate whatever format you want. (It won't be a template because LaTeX doesn't use templates.)

Comment: By Digital SAT I assume you're referring to the new CollegeBoard SAT exams? That's a weird thing to recreate, let alone ask someone else to recreate, and I agree with @cfr that the demand is pretty unreasonable. What's the goal of recreating the exam format? Aren't they supposed to be taken on a laptop anyway?

Comment: About the photo: just select the image, not its file, copy&paste it into your question. This web interface will store it with a link AND provide some text markup. It‘s easy to do, and perhaps a bit surprising, may be, and works fine.